# The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint

Tags: java, android

The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions

//
I think I have properly assigned the package name and sha key.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=9&chart=mostPopular&q=&regionCode=KR&type=video&pageToken=&key=AIzaSyCgfBMMgbhREQ-WoztivqyscWN2auEFlIo

W/user.easyforyo: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=9&chart=mostPopular&q=&regionCode=KR&type=video&pageToken=&key=AIzaSyCgfBMMgbhREQ-WoztivqyscWN2auEFlIo http/1.1
    --> END GET
D/AAAAA: onResume
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
W/user.easyforyo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe6b11980, tid 5595
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe6b7e440: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe6b7e440: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xee952d60)
D/AAAAA: onCreateOptionsMenu
W/user.easyforyo: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/AutoCompleteTextView;->doBeforeTextChanged()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/AutoCompleteTextView;->doAfterTextChanged()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/AutoCompleteTextView;->ensureImeVisible(Z)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/user.easyforyo: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe6b7e440: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xee952d60)
D/OkHttp: <-- 403  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=9&chart=mostPopular&q=&regionCode=KR&type=video&pageToken=&key=AIzaSyCgfBMMgbhREQ-WoztivqyscWN2auEFlIo (459ms)
D/OkHttp: vary: Origin
    vary: X-Origin
    content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    date: Mon, 13 May 2019 22:33:42 GMT
    expires: Mon, 13 May 2019 22:33:42 GMT
    cache-control: private, max-age=0
    x-content-type-options: nosniff
    x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    server: GSE
    alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
D/OkHttp: {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
D/OkHttp:    {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
        "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=1036386000837"
       }
      ],
D/OkHttp:   "code": 403,
      "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?